# Why can't I create an extended partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to install Ubuntu with Windows 10. After opening GParted, I've noticed that there are about 4 partitions (I don't know what type they are). Then, as most tutorials show, I needed to create an extended partition. I took some space from Windows disk D. After that, I chose that unallocated space to create extended partition, but I couldn't because it was not available to click. I can create only primary partitions. What do I have to do?

I need to create an extended partition so that I can create logical partitions for home, swap and root. Can I do all this things in a primary partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extended partitions are not used in GPT. Since you're using Windows 10, it's usually the case that your partition table is GPT and you can create as many primary partitions as you need. Run `sudo parted -l`, which should list the "Partition Table". If that's GPT, go ahead with creating primary partitions.

Comment: My computer suppots UEFI, but after clicking F2 , I come to BIOS. Does it mean that my partition table is GPT? Maybe it is MBR?

Comment: You mean you turned on legacy boot. No, that does not change your partition table. Legacy boot works just fine on GPT. But UEFI systems with Windows have GPT by default.

Comment: As I've understood my partition table is GPT(am I right?) . You mean that I need to create 3 primary partitions for swap,home and root?

Comment: Run `sudo parted -l`, as I have said in the answer. That should tell you whether you're right or wrong.

Comment: You mean that I need to create 3 primary partitions for swap,home and root? Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. The limit is 128 or so, IIRC, in GPT.

Comment: @user202912 -- on uefi computers, pressing F2 brings up a system settings menu,  it is not a BIOS ... though it looks the same.

Comment: @muru I've divided free space for root(12 gb), swap(4 gb) and home(about 60+gb) . And in installing Ubuntu,I need to choose root folder ?